# java string.trim method implement detail

Tags: java

```
public String trim() {
    int len = value.length;
    int st = 0;
    char[] val = value;    /* avoid getfield opcode */

    while ((st < len) && (val[st] <= ' ')) {
        st++;
    }
    while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= ' ')) {
        len--;
    }
    return ((st > 0) || (len < value.length)) ? substring(st, len) : this;
}
```

1. why `val[st] <= ' '`,not `val[st] == ''`.
2. what is `(st > 0) || (len < value.length)` meaning.

Comment: "to filter values less than space" which is described in the Javadoc.

Comment: The first question is good, but the second question seems to just be about understanding the syntax or logic here - you're probably better off consulting a textbook, or doing some debugging, to understand that; alternatively, you should clarify what exactly you don't understand about it (and separate this into two questions).

Comment: Thank you very much.I understand is after debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `''` isn't even a possible character. Assuming it's a typo and you mean to ask why `<= ' '` is used instead of `== ' '`:

`' '` (a space) has the unicode value 32. Since `.trim` not only removes spaces, but also tabs and newlines (with unicode values `9` and `10` respectively), `(val[st] <= ' ')` is used because it's shorter than `(val[st] == '\t' || val[st] == '\n' || val[st] == ' ')` (the other unicode values in the range `[0, 32)` besides tab and new-lines are unprintables / control characters, so they just get trimmed as well apparently).

---

2) `return ((st > 0) || (len < value.length)) ? substring(st, len) : this;` means that if any trailing and/or leading whitespaces were found, they are removed by  returning the substring in the range `[str, len)`. If there were no leading nor trailing whitespaces, `this` (the String input itself) is returned instead.

NOTE / fun fact: This also means you could do something like `boolean containsTrailingAndOrLeadingWhitespaces = strInput.trim() != strInput;` instead of `!strInput.trim().equals(strInput)`, because the `String` itself (and thus the same reference) is returned instead of a new String (not recommended, though).

Comment: Thank you very much. I already understand after see you commond.

Answer (score 3):

1. `val[st] == ''` syntactically incorrect. `''` is not `char` literal.
2. `st > 0` mean starting position is not `0`, `len < value.length` length is less then length of string. This is optimization which return `this` in case there is nothing to trim.

**EDIT**

In case of your first question is about why it is not check for `val[st] == ' '` the answer is: it is because `trim` not only remove white spaces, but also new lines and tabs. In fact it remove a lot of non printable characters like '\b' (charcter that make sound when printed). All of those characters have [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) code less then 32 (code of whitespace).

Comment: I think the OP meant `' '` not `''`

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'll extend my answer to cover this.

Comment: why is val[st] <= '  ', not val[st] == '  '....thanks

Comment: @zzcrontoby because you don't just want to trim spaces, but also other whitespace characters (e.g. newline, tab, carriage return...).

Comment: Thank you very much. I already understand after see you commond.I should learn more about ASCII and other basic conception.

Answer (score 2):

`trim()` strips space and control characters at the start or end of a String.

When you do `<= ' '` you check for space or any control character.

```
return ((st > 0) || (len < value.length)) ? substring(st, len) : this;
```

You can see in this line that it only takes a substring if it would make the String smaller otherwise it returns the original String.

You could argue this check is redundant as `substring` performs the same check

```
    return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == value.length)) ? this
            : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
```

However, this avoids a bounds check if the string isn't trimmed.  Even better would be to avoid a bounds check even if a substring is taken.

Comment: Thank you very much. I already understand after see you commond.I should learn more about ASCII and other basic conception.

Comment: @zzcrontoby my first language was machine language so I had to memorise the ASCII table, be glad you don't ;).